# py2app data file not accessible to user

Tags: python, py2app

I have created an app using python and packaged it with py2app.

I have an excel file that is updated using a GUI and want this excel file accessible to the user. However currently the excel file is hidden and needs to be accessed by "Show Package Contents" and is stored under Resources.

Considering the app is run from Desktop, how do I make the excel file available on Desktop.

I could not find information on how to do this.

Comment: If you want a file copied to the desktop, then your script has to copy it to the desktop.

Comment: I understand, is there any way I can get the path of the executable? I tried and I am getting the path from resources, where the python file is running.

Comment: `os.path.abspath(os.path.dir(__file__))` gives you the directory containing the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Py2app by design does not contain functionality for this.

First of all an application bundle conceptually is a read-only and should not contain mutable data. Any mutable data should be stored outside of the app bundle itself.

The app can off course contain a template/initial version for that you copy to whatever location you choose to store the mutable copy.  Creating that copy is something you must code yourself in the application.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get the path in the script and saving it. Since the script runs from the resource folder, the file is getting stored in the resource folder. 
I want to get the path of the executable, so that I can save it on the same path.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by taking the long route. Created a file dialog to get the directory the user wants to save the file and get the location from there.